# Can some regions of space (independent of size), be completely devoid of matter?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, mass, universe, matter

Before answering the question, keep in mind that I am a second year Biology student, with no experience in studying Physics and a very basic understanding of Mathematics. However, I have some experience studying introductory Chemistry.

---

Edit: I have re-worded, decluttered and re-titled the post with the intention of elucidating my question. I apologise and thank those who answered the initial question. Initially, the question was, "If no region of space is completely devoid of matter, how can some regions have more matter compared to others?". However, the question relied on the assumption that all regions of space (irrespective of size) contain matter. This assumption must be addressed.

Allegedly, every region in space, no matter how big or small, possesses matter, which seems to contradict the notion that matter has a non-uniform distribution in space, *as well as*, the belief that atoms are mostly empty space.

*If* matter composes *all* regions of space, how can *some* regions have more matter (i.e., mass) compared to others? If the assumption is incorrect, this question is superfluous.

Here is an example that may provide insight into my thinking: I *assume*, in order for air to be less dense than say a solid object, air must have less particles (matter) per volume compared to the solid object. Would air not have more empty space, compared to the solid object? Even if the assumption is incorrect, is my 'thinking' correct?

Comment: Where are you getting "matter composes all regions of nature"?  That's not in your quote.

Comment: Gravity is modeled with gravitational fields created by matter. Gravitational fields are not "matter" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a mix of false premises and non-sequiturs. Firstly, matter does not 'compose' space. Secondly, even if it did, that would not rule out an uneven distribution. My acoustic guitar is composed of wood, wood that is unevenly distributed.

Yes, every sizeable region of space might contain some matter, but it does not follow that the matter cannot be unevenly distributed. Take two random cubic metres of space. One might contain five hydrogen atoms- the other might contain parts of me and my laptop, ergo matter can be unevenly distributed.

When you say that any region of space, however small, is 'allegedly' not devoid of matter, you ought to name the scoundrel making such reckless allegations. Air is indeed less dense than wood precisely because the particles of matter of which air is composed are more widely spread and thus have more empty space around them.

I was going to vote to close your question on the grounds that it was complete nonsense, but an odd sense of politeness and benevolence forbade me.

Comment: Ah my new friend Macro (I remember you from Philosophy SE), thankyou for actually addressing my question, whilst your response was a bit harsh, it is one of few that addresses my question. Ok so, "matter does not 'compose' space", so I assume it takes up space instead, is this not the same thing? If not, what actually composes space?

Comment: As for the "scoundrel making such reckless allegations", well I'm not going to point fingers, but if you read some of the answers I got, this was suggested. I was told "no volume of space is completely empty of matter". Maybe this caused my confusion. I wish I would have got a simple 'some volumes of space are devoid of matter', earlier. Nevertheless, if you are indeed correct, thank you, champ.

Comment: Hi Simon, my harshness was tongue in cheek! Always a pleasure to see you! Best wishes.

Comment: I suspected that, the humour went over my small head, haha.

Answer (score 1):

The universe does not have an even distribution of matter.

First consider that the early universe was an extremely dense and energetic region, *very much* smaller than it is now. The matter distribution was not completely uniform. Classical mechanics would tell us that it should have been, and you may have been correct in your assumptions. But quantum mechanics does not allow this. In fact, at that time there were *quantum fluctuations*, or matter and energy fluctuations, located throughout this region.

During the expansion of the universe, these fluctuations were spread throughout an increasingly growing universe, giving us regions of matter like stars, galaxies etc., and the converse, regions devoid of matter.

A more detailed explanation of this can be found in [this](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v13/16) article on APS:

"*A fundamental task of modern cosmology is to understand the formation of structure in our Universe from its earliest moments. The leading idea is that of inflation [1, 2], which can successfully explain many observed features of our Universe, from its flatness to its isotropy. Inflation produces an extremely homogeneous Universe, but quantum fluctuations create fluctuations in density from place to place. These fluctuations become the seeds of the large-scale structure of today’s Universe—a foam-like texture of voids and galaxy clusters, sheets, and filaments...Nathan Musoke and colleagues from the University of Auckland, New Zealand, take small initial quantum fluctuations and predict their evolution with a high-precision numerical computation.*"

Comment: At one point you say "regions devoid of matter", what is the evidence for this?

Comment: Regions without stars, clusters, galaxies etc? The evidence is obtained by either looking up, using a telescope or looking at satellite imagery of space. I’m not sure why you ask that question. Seems obvious. Of course “devoid” doesn’t mean perfectly empty/vacuum.

Comment: your sentences read with ambiguity. I am asking whether any region, no matter how big or small can be devoid of matter and what reasons we have to believe this.  

Here is the Google definition of devoid: *entirely lacking or free from*. Thus, I assume devoid of matter means regions entirely without matter. Nonetheless, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Simon There is actually no ambiguity. One thing you should note is that although we refer to space as "vacuum" (devoid of matter), what we mean is extremely low pressure i.e., a few molecules per meter cubed in most regions. But for all intents and purposes, we can assume it to be. And your OP is "_why is matter not equally distributed in space_" which is inconsistent with your comment above. The answer I gave, and others, addresses this. If you are now asking "_whether any region, no matter how big or small can be devoid of matter_" you should post another question. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @joseph h I have followed your advice and re-titled the question.

Answer (score 1):

The *fundamental strength* of gravity (that is, the leading "G" term in Newton's gravity equation) is the same everywhere. What differs from place to place is instead just how much matter is contained within each region of the universe- and this number is highly nonuniform, with some regions containing enormous amounts of matter and others almost none.

This nonuniform distribution of matter in the observable universe dates back to the very beginnings of the universe, very shortly after the Big Bang, when random quantum fluctuations caused the very uniform distribution of matter present then to clump up in some spots and thin out in others.

These random nonuniformities served as seeds to trigger the gravitational clumping-up of matter into galaxies, galaxy clusters, and superclusters, separated by almost completely empty space.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I assume that in order for a region of three-dimensional space to have more matter compared to another region of three-dimensional space, of the same volume, some percentage of the region with less matter, must be devoid of matter.

Comment: This naturally inclines me to ask the question, is matter infinitely or finitely divisible. Perhaps, I am being to philosophical, but logic is the basis for science and philosophy is a fundamental part of science.

Comment: 1) not true. no volume of space is *completely* empty of matter; there will always be at least a couple of hydrogen molecules roaming around in every cubic kilometer of space. 2) one apple cannot fill that region entirely- your logic makes no sense here. 3) matter is not infinitely divisible.

Comment: I have no idea where you are coming from, and I don't see this conversation going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This question's title has changed since some answers were posted, so I'll address the current version, but in doing so may repeat others' points.

The early universe had [random small-scale fluctuations in its density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_fluctuations), but gravity accentuated this, with particles being pulled towards already higher-density areas. There are [still some open questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_formation_and_evolution#Formation_of_disk_galaxies) on *exactly* how this worked, because multiple locations in which matter coalesces can also be drawn together by the gravity between them, and the relative timing of these events is unclear. But regardless of such subtleties, it was inevitable matter would clump.

In fact, it has done so in a "fractal" (nested) way, meaning the aforementioned "top-down vs bottom-up" debate repeats at several levels. [Cosmic voids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_(astronomy)) are bordered by [galaxy filaments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_filament), composed of [superclusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercluster), composed of [clusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_cluster) and [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_group) of galaxies, in which stars are similarly organized. (In a recycling of terminology, a galaxy comprises [super star clusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_star_cluster) composed of several types of smaller [star clusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_cluster).) At each level in the hierarchy, there are many bodies which locally attract matter to comparatively small regions of space, separated by greater length scales. For example, stars are at most a few light seconds wide, but one star may be several light years from any others.

A star is itself a small-scale version of this "rich get richer" density principle, with a hydrogen cloud eventually collapsing to form one or in some cases several stars. We can also go smaller: from the rings of matter surrounding a young star, discrete objects condense, such as planets, moons, asteroids etc.; we are [somewhat inexpert](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/715312) on the exact details here too.

Answer (score -1):

We understand ordinary matter to be composed of atoms. You cannot divide an atom in half. You can deconstruct it into constituent "particles", but you also cannot divide those in half. Most of the matter in the universe is of very low density, so you may consider it to be atoms or particles occupying only a small part of the volume. Space is mostly empty.

But it's not uniform. Gravity pulls matter from less dense regions to denser regions, making the denser regions more dense and the less dense regions even less dense. Orbital motions and thermal pressure resist this, but heat radiates away, so the thermal pressure tends to decline with time. Thus, matter collapses into clusters.

At the smallest scales, quantum mechanical Pauli force resists the collapse, and we get high-density objects: asteroids, planets, white dwarf stars, and neutron stars. If Pauli force doesn't suffice, collapse continues to a black hole.

Comment: Thank you @John Doty, everything you have said is logical to me, however, you stated that the constituent particles of atoms cannot be divided in half, firstly, by infinitely divisible I meant that particles are themselves composed of particles, and so on, forever. Secondly, that statement is a hypothesis, are there any observations supporting that hypothesis?

Comment: @Simon First, don't idolize logic. Logic is a human invention, useful for modeling reality, but an atom knows nothing of logic. The basic answer is that we have a well-tested model of matter and energy, the "standard model", in which all visible matter is composed of indivisible leptons and quarks. If they are composed of something else, we have no technology to deconstruct them, nor do we know of any natural process that does so. Astronomical "dark matter" is much less well understood: all we can say is that what we know of its gravitational dynamics matches what we expect from particles.

Comment: What difficulty do you have with this, oh downvoter?

Comment: firstly, thank you though for clarifying the divisibility of particle question I proposed. Secondly, it was not me who downvoted, unfortunately, I am asking the same question to those who downvoting my question.